# Problem getting generic extension method to work correctly

Tags: c#, generics, list, extension-methods, hashset

I'm trying to create the extension method AddRange for HashSet so I can do something like this:

```
var list = new List<Item>{ new Item(), new Item(), new Item() };
var hashset = new HashSet<Item>();
hashset.AddRange(list);
```

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, List<T> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        collection.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Problem is, when I try to use AddRange, I'm getting this compiler error:

`The type arguments for method 'AddRange<T>(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>, System.Collections.Generic.List<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

In other words, I have to end up using this instead:

```
hashset.AddRange<Item>(list);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Strange, I pasted your code snippets (along with an empty definition for Item) into a new console project, and it works for me.

Comment: This should work fine... could you post a complete code illustrating the problem ? As a side note : you should declare the parameter as `IEnumerable<T>`, not `List<T>`, it will give you more flexibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine for me:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, List<T> list)
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

class Item {}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Item>{ new Item(), new Item(), new Item() };
        var hashset = new HashSet<Item>();
        hashset.AddRange(list);
    }
}
```

Could you give a similar short but complete program which fails to compile?

Comment: I figured out the problem, but it was unrelated to the extension method. Rather, I was trying to implicitly cast a List to a HashSet, which didn't work and caused the extension method to be unable to implicitly cast it as well.

Comment: Others, before using this accepted answer in your code, see the answer below using UnionWith.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve a range of elements from hashset when provided with start index and count just like GetRange() for lists?

Comment: @inquisitive: That doesn't make any logical sense, as hash sets aren't logically ordered. It's entirely possible that if you add an item, the whole set will get reordered. You can use Skip/Take from LINQ, but doing so suggests you shouldn't be using `HashSet` to start with.

Answer (score 29):

Use

```
hashSet.UnionWith<Item>(list);
```

Comment: UnionWish modifies the HashSet to contain just common elements. AddRange is supposed to add ell elements from the specific collection to the HasSet.

Comment: No it's not. UnionWith has similar meaning as List.AddRange. You seem to be mixing it with IntersectWith.