# simulate List like hashSet in C# so that List will have noduplicate values

Tags: c#, list

I want to add colections to List, but only if Advertisements does not already exist in it. I know that HashSet works like this that has no duplicate values, but with HashSet i can not use AddRange and GetRange.

So is it possible to simulate List like hashSet?

```
List<Advertisements> advertisements = new List<Advertisements>();

advertisements.AddRange(NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria<Advertisements>()
.CreateCriteria(AdvertisementsProperties.City.ToString())
.Add(Restrictions.Or(
Restrictions.Like(CitiesProperties.Name.ToString(), text, MatchMode.Anywhere),
Restrictions.Like(CitiesProperties.SlovenianName.ToString(), text, MatchMode.Anywhere)))
.List<Advertisements>());

advertisements.AddRange(NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria<Advertisements>()
.CreateCriteria(AdvertisementsProperties.Area.ToString())
.Add(Restrictions.Or(
Restrictions.Like(AreasProperties.Name.ToString(), text, MatchMode.Anywhere),
Restrictions.Like(AreasProperties.SlovenianName.ToString(), text, MatchMode.Anywhere)))
.List<Advertisements>());
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question - Do you want to use AddRange/GetRange with HashSet? Which collection are you trying to work with? I'm afraid your answers will be fairly incomplete without a better defined question. It is confusing as to which collection you are trying to use.

Comment: i want that only one element will be in list like in hashset. So no noduplicate values. Another option is to use sort and getRange in hashset which i think is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably want to create your own class if you often need a hybrid List/Set collection functionality. It would go something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ListSet<T> : IList<T>, ISet<T> // ISet<T> is supported only from .NET 4.0 on
{
    #region Inner collections

    private HashSet<T> _innerSet = new HashSet<T>();
    private List<T> _innerList = new List<T>();

    #endregion

    #region The read methods delegate to the inner collection which is more appropriate and efficient:

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return this._innerSet.Contains(item);
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return this._innerList.IndexOf(item);
    }

    // TODO: Implement all other read operations

    #endregion

    #region The write methods must keep both inner collections synchronized

    public bool Add(T item)
    {
        bool wasAdded = this._innerSet.Add(item);
        if (wasAdded) this._innerList.Add(item);

        return wasAdded;
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (T item in items) this.Add(item);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        if (this._innerSet.Remove(item))
        {
            return this._innerList.Remove(item);
        }

        return false;
    }

    // TODO: Implement all other write operations
    // TODO: Consider implementing roll back mechanisms in exception handlers
    //            when write operations fail

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: herzmeister der welten maybe do you have whole class written somewhere becouse it is very interested class? regards

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve a range of elements from hashset when provided with start index and count just like GetRange() for lists?

Comment: no, a `HashSet<T>` does not remember the order in which items were inserted, as it internally the its items indexed by their hashes. So some kind of `GetRange()` functionality would make no sense. If you `foreach` through the set, or you use some LINQ operations, you'd get the items back in a somewhat random order. So you'd also need this hybrid class in this case. To implement that method you'd just do `this._innerList.GetRange(...)`.

Answer (score 15):

To add a bunch of items to a `HashSet` like `AddRange` does simply use:

```
set.UnionWith(items);
```

The items in a `HashSet` are not indexed (it's implemented as a hash table which is not designed for index based access to elements). If you strictly need to store items by index, you'll have to use a simple list and create your own `Add` method that checks `Contains` on each element before adding it to the underlying list. Of course, a linear list doesn't provide the efficiency of set operations as `HashSet` does.

Comment: Unless he needs to preserve insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583228/problem-getting-generic-extension-method-to-work-correctly). The poster used an extension method to add "AddRange" functionality to HashSet.

Comment: This is a bad thing to do with a `HashSet`. It already provides a means to add an arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>` (possibly more efficiently than adding a sequence one by one).